# Can a neural network have fractional values in output nodes?

Tags: neural-network

I have learned that for detecting a handwritten digit, an ANN will have 10 nodes in the output layer where each of them will represent a digit and will carry a 1 if the corresponding digit agrees and a 0 otherwise.
I would like to know if I want outputs in fractions in each of the nodes in the output layer that sums up to 1, for example, detecting color composition of an image - 0.5 Blue, 0.2 Green and 0.3 Red. How is it possible with ANN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass your layer outputs through a softmax operation, The softmax function outputs a probability any class being the true class and it sums to 1.

Comment: Oh, thank you very much. Now, after searching about softmax, I'm reading http://dataaspirant.com/2017/03/07/difference-between-softmax-function-and-sigmoid-function/. This is exactly what I wanted.